# How to add a leading 0 in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to add a leading 0 in a column called `houses`, where it is a unique list of 3 digits, but I wanted have to add a leading 0 to it --> so 4 digits instead of 3.
Can someone help me with this query as the code is incompatible in the '|' operator.

The code is as follows:

```
select houses from house_numbers
order by houses;
select houses, 
case
    when len(houses)=3 then '0' | houses
    when len(houses)=4 then '' | houses
end as houses
from house_numbers
```

Comment: Being new is no excuse for no research, look at the documentation for string concatenation

Comment: What is the data type for column `houses` ?

Answer (score 2):

The string concatenation operator in SQL Server is `+`, not `||`, so you should use:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN LEN(houses) = 3 THEN '0' + houses
    WHEN LEN(houses) = 4 THEN '' + houses
END AS houses
```

However, a better way to do this would be to just left pad with zero to a length of 4:

```sql
RIGHT('0000' + ISNULL(houses, ''), 4) AS houses
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, very important to point out that doing case when is unnecessary here.

Comment: I'm not sure replacing NULL with '0000' is required

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `CONCAT` function here, assuming you are dealing with varchars

```
when len(houses)=3 then CONCAT('0' , houses)
```

You could simplify like so

```
select houses from house_numbers
order by houses;
select houses, 
case
    when len(houses)=3 then CONCAT('0' , houses)
    else houses
end as houses
from house_numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Always add the Zero and then strip of the right 4 chars, I believe this might be less resource intensive than doing a case

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),345),4) AS Three_Digit_Example,
       RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),1345),4) AS Four_Digit_Example
```